# Windows 10 sandbox can't access the internet when the host using VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-sandbox

I am currently running Surfshark VPN on Windows 10 and then when I launch Windows Sandbox, I have no internet in it. Once I stopped the Surfshark VPN, the Windows Sandbox can access internet.

I want to let Windows Sandbox access internet through the VPN in host.

- Edition:  Windows 10 Pro
- Version:  21H2
- OS build: 19044.2965
- Experience:   Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Comment: Make sure the VPN has Split Tunnel and that it is enabled.

Comment: No, I don't want Windows Sandbox bypass the VPN. Can Windows Sandbox also go through the VPN connection?

Comment: It may be that Sandbox security does not allow VPN. I am not certain but that is probably the case. I have used Sandbox and it is utterly secure.